# Render comments in a custom Twig template

Tags: 8, comments

I rewrite the article tpl **page--article.html.twig** and I want to render the comments and the comments form.

I add the comments in the content type fields and try to render with `{{ node.comment | render }}`, but it's not work.

Is it possible to render it in a custom tpl?

Answer (score 3):

After adding comments as field in your content type

In **node--article.html.twig** :

{{ content.field_myfieldnamecomments }}

Comment: It's working for node view, But not for the node preview, How can we show the comment section for node preview as well ?

Answer (score 2):

In template files for a content type (eg page--article.html.twig), you have the 'content' variable available. I use this bit of Twig to render the whole comments block:-

```
{{ content.comment }}
```